# Apache: Central Virtual Host configuration per domain

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm having some problems configuring multiple domains in my apache instance.

I have 2 domains: **a.com** and **b.com**
I only want to configure the cert files once, so i have a configuration for a.com and b.com. But if i have something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName a.com
        ServerAlias www.a.com *.a.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/fullchain-a.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/privkey-a.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName b.com
        ServerAlias www.b.com *.b.com

        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /path/fullchain-b.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/privkey-b.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

it wont allow me to define subdomains in seperate configuration files. Because of the whole wildcard stuff, it just doesn't care about the following vhosts.

Is there a way to configure the certificates centrally so all subdomain vhosts will automatically default to them, without having to specify the whole path in each and every subdomain config?

So i just need to do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName subdomain.b.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html-b
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName subdomain.a.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html-a
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName test.a.com
        ServerAlias test.b.com
 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/shared-html
</VirtualHost>
```

or do i need to specify the certificate paths for each subdomain?

I tried using multiple *default* vhosts, but it would always default to the fist one.

Comment: You can simply place the certificate directives in a file which you then include in the vhost sections. That centralizes the certificate directives and allows to change paths easily.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking about that as well, but if i want to use two domains for the same directory i would need to define the vhost twice. That wouldnt fix the issue with my third example.

Comment: That is not how Apache works.  You can only have 1 VirtualHost that matches a domain.  Apache will not know which VirtualHost section to use if you define the same domain in two sections.

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand your issue. You indeed can only have one default host. That is the idea behind a default host: it is THE default host. And no, you don't have to define two vhosts if both hosts share the same DOCUMENT_ROOT. You can use a single vhost, set a server name and a server alias for the two domains in there. And set or include the certificate once for that host. However that means that your certificate needs to name BOTH domains, obviously.

Comment: Yeah, so there is no way around combining the two certificates, thats what i thought. I was hoping that im able to let apache match 2 vhosts and combine those entries.